# Toggle search bar when in small screen

Tags: javascript

I want to make search bar toggle when in small screen. should look like this [image]

This is the wide screen img [image]

Is there any reference or particular code that i need to add?

```
<form class="expanding-search-form">              
          <input class="search-input" id="global-search" type="search" placeholder="Search">
          <div class="search-dropdown">
            <button class="button dropdown-toggle" type="button">
              <span class="toggle-active">Projects</span>
              <span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="menu-active"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">External Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>          
          <button class="button search-button" formaction="search-contact.html">
                    <span class="fa fa-search">
                          <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                    </span>
              </button>
        </form>

$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          $(this).closest('.search-dropdown').toggleClass('open');
        });

        $('.dropdown-menu > li > a').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var clicked = $(this);
          clicked.closest('.dropdown-menu').find('.menu-active').removeClass('menu-active');
          clicked.parent('li').addClass('menu-active');
          clicked.closest('.search-dropdown').find('.toggle-active').html(clicked.html());
        });

        $(document).click(function() {
          $('.search-dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
        });
```

Comment: This would be better suited to be handled with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
<form class="expanding-search-form" >              
          <input class="search-input" id="global-search" type="search" placeholder="Search">
           <button class="search-dropdown-button">
             <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
           </button>
           
          <div class="search-dropdown">
            <button class="button dropdown-toggle" type="button">
              <span class="toggle-active">Projects</span>
              <span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="menu-active"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">External Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button class="button search-button" formaction="search-contact.html">
                    Search
              </button>
          </div>          
          
        </form>
```

```
.search-dropdown{
   display:none; 
 }
.search-dropdown.open{
  display:block;
}
.dropdown-menu.open{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}
```

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).closest('.search-dropdown').find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
 });

$('.search-dropdown-button').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('.search-dropdown').toggleClass('open');
});

$('.dropdown-menu > li > a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var clicked = $(this);
   clicked.closest('.dropdown-menu').find('.menu-active').removeClass('menu-active');
   clicked.parent('li').addClass('menu-active');
   clicked.closest('.search-dropdown').find('.toggle-active').html(clicked.html());
 });

$(document).click(function() {
   $('.search-dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
 });
```

You have to create a button for `.search-dropdown` and put it outside of `.search-dropdown` and add some CSS for toggling.

Comment: its not toggle in small screen

Comment: @Tat When clicking on search button , `search-dropdown`  toggles (appears and disappers). You can use media queries for larger screens